# Using CSS to make header sticky and scroll body

Tags: css, scroll, header, sticky

I have tried several versions of this and I always come back to either the header expanding in size as I scroll or the th and td cells not being the same width.
Please see this fiddle for full html and css:  It scrolls beautifully but you will see that that `th` and `td` are progressively out of line with each other.
    https://jsfiddle.net/paul724/0gL74yd1/4/#&togetherjs=udj4PqtUOg

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="th-right" >Fruit</th>
        <th class="td-left" >Colour</th>
        <th class="td-left" >Status</th>
        <th class="th-right" >Number
        <span class="up" text-align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; back to top &uarr;<span>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given width of the td and th in percentage. If width is mentioned in percentage then the "td" or "th" column adjusts its size according to the percentage size of the word written inside. "Percentage" is used to define the width of the containing block.
So in the line no. "33" of your given at fiddle change width in pixels as desired. Try using below correction. It fixes the inconsistency.

```
tbody td, thead th {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

For making header and footer sticky. You need to add the following css. For footer you have to just fix bottom as 0.

```
 .th{
     position: sticky;
     top:0;
    }
.footer th{
   position: sticky;
   bottom:0;
   }
```

To make the whole table the same width as the 4 columns of content:

This problem occurs because you have used block level elements by setting display:block. Due to 100% width gets fixed but in code 100px width is also fixed and float:left is done due to which if content inside the block exceeds 100px it goes on to the next block.

Solution: Just remove display:block and float:left and do not fix the width as 100px.

Comment: thank you - it works really well and I particularly appreciate the clarity of your explanation.  I find there are always secondary questions - in this case there are two.

Comment: The first is to how to make the whole table the same width as the 4 columns of content?  At the moment the shaded rows extend to the right by almost double the size of the content, before the scroll bar appears

Comment: The second is - can we use the same techniques to make a sticky footer?  For example with a total of all the numbers?

Comment: I have added a "total" row at the bottom.

Comment: The header is also not fixed. I have edited the answer to accomodate all your queries, Hope it helps now. Also I am not able to see the "total" row at the bottom added by you. It is not reflecting in fiddle.

Comment: Thank you - all coming together.  Please revisit the jsfiddle (sorry I forgot the footer earlier it is in there now).  Is it possible to vary the width of each column?  Either auto based on content or fixed px?  And I think last question - can the footer be made to always display at the bottom of the screen - wherever the user has scrolled to?  Again really appreciated your clarity.

Comment: For footer you have to just add the css as mentioned  above "footer". Yes it is possible to vary the width of each column. You have to add the desired width in a class. And add that classname to each column where you want vary the width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211479/discussion-between-paul724-and-927tanmay).